# Advice on tracking down Crashlytics bug report

Tags: android, debugging, stack-trace, gson

I'm tasked with finding and fixing the following error generated from an automated test, generated from Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mgensuite.lockscreen.receiver.SyncEventsReceiver: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "21474836&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&缪缪缪缪倀Ϲ倀Ϲ倀Ϲ..."
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2517)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:932)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:748)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I'm entirely new to this code base and tech stack and have no idea how to go about finding out the cause of this bug. None of these methods are referenced in the code base itself. What are some tips on diagnosing the problem?

In the off chance any of you recognize what is going on, some advice on this specific issue would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is a numberFormatException in the following line

```
`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mgensuite.lockscreen.receiver.SyncEventsReceiver: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "21474836&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&缪缪缪缪倀Ϲ倀Ϲ倀Ϲ..."`
```

Your app is generating a string that is formatted as a double, while it contains elements other than just digits and decimal points.
You might want to go and check where such a string is generated in your app and start debugging from there.